# Set returnUrl

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

How do I set the return URL when using the `fb-login-button`? I want to redirect the current authenticated user to another page (not the root (default.aspx))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `on-login` parameter of `fb:login-button` to redirect to a different page.

This parameter can call a JavaScript function to perform the redirect, so you could do something like this:

```
<fb:login-button
on-login="RedirectLogon()"
/>

<script type="text/javascript">
function RedirectLogon {
    window.location='nextpage.html'
}
</script>
```

Hope this helps.